# PayPal iOS SDK's Credentials

Tags: ios, paypal

i am using new paypal ios SDK.

i have successfully implemented it into my code.
but into code it is asking for kPayPalClientId and kPayPalReceiverEmail.
how to get these two credential.
also it has customerId in a function that is triggered on touch event of button named with Pay.

please provide me full description/tutorial for this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the error text from the console?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/ provides the tutorial.

- In step #3, you need to put in `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` as the `client_id` you get from the applications tab.
- You'll also need to replace `YOUR_PAYPAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS` with the PayPal account email that will receive the payment. It should be the same one you logged in with to create the `client_id`.